# Camel CXF SOAP API Consumer with https and Security Header

Tags: soap, apache-camel, cxf, ws-security, camel-cxf

I'm currently facing the issue, that I can not consume a SOAP webservice via camel-cxf. The exception is the following:

```
org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied:
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportBinding: Received Timestamp does not match the requirements
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}IncludeTimestamp
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:179) ~[109:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-policy:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.handle(PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.java:102) ~[109:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-policy:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44) ~[109:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-ws-policy:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[78:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:813) [78:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1695) [102:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream$1.run(HTTPConduit.java:1194) [102:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.2.6]
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:421) [78:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.2.6]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:?]
        at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:346) [78:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.2.6]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:?]
```

and the SOAP answer the following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">a:InvalidSecurity</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="de-DE">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I used the maven `cxf-codegen-plugin` to generate the Java-classes via the `wsdl2java` goal.
The security part of the wsdl looks like this:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagementService_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                            sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:UsernameToken>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy/>
            </sp:Wss10>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

and I want to use the `UsernameToken` authentication.

Maven dependencies:

camel version: 2.20.3

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-soap-starter</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.6</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried to connect to the api via SoapUI and everything worked well. Either with the authentication-part of SoapUI or with specifying the security part in the SoapHeader, both worked.

My camel route-builder looks like this:

```
SoapJaxbDataFormat soap = new SoapJaxbDataFormat("org.tempuri", new ServiceInterfaceStrategy(IUserManagementService.class, true));


from("direct:userdata.soap.requests")
// .marshal(soap) // not sure, if I need to marshal here
.to("cxf://{{SOAP_URL}}" +
        "?serviceClass=org.tempuri.IUserManagementService" +
        "&serviceName={http://tempuri.org/}UserManagementService" +
        "&endpointName={http://tempuri.org/}BasicHttpBinding_IUserManagementService" +
        "&wsdlURL={{WSDL_URL}}" +
        "&dataFormat=MESSAGE" +
        "&username={{SOAP_USERNAME}}" +
        "&password={{SOAP_PASSWORD}}" +
          "&allowStreaming=false");
```

and I'm sending to the queue like this:

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:userdata.soap.requests")
Endpoint endpoint;

@Produce(uri = "direct:userdata.soap.requests")
ProducerTemplate channel;

....

private Object sendRequest(Object request, String operationName) throws Exception{
    Exchange inExchange = endpoint.createExchange(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
    inExchange.getIn().setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, operationName);
    inExchange.getIn().setHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAMESPACE, "http://tempuri.org/");
    inExchange.getIn().setBody(request);

    Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<>();
    context.put("ws-security.username", soapUsername);
    context.put("ws-security.password", soapPassword);
    inExchange.getIn().setHeader(Client.REQUEST_CONTEXT, context);

    Exchange outExchange = channel.send(inExchange);
    log.error(outExchange.getOut().getBody(String.class));
    Object result = outExchange.getIn().getBody(Object.class);
    if(result.getClass().equals(FaultException.class)){
        throw (FaultException) result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

where `endpoint` is type `org.apache.camel.Endpoint` and `channel` is type `org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate`

The `request`-Object is of type from the autogenerated classes by the plugin.

I also tried, writing my own WSS4JOutInterceptor to handle the security part, but this also did not work.

Please let me know, if I need to provide more information.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out, there was an issue, interpreting the SOAP answer.
So actually the route works like this. Just set the headers `ws-security.username` and `ws-security.password` and the cxf will take care of creating the correct header.
I've also changed the dataformat to `PAYLOAD` and marshalling is not needed at this point.

Thanks anyway for reading